# Access DBContext using EF7 and VNext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dbcontext, entity-framework-core

In my MVC 6 project I have my `ApplicationDBContext` class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {

    }
}
```

This is added to my services in the Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
  //Other configurations removed for brevity
}
```

Now when I create a new Controller, it asks me if I want to use the Entity Framework, and I can choose my data context.  When that controller is created the context is passed in the constructor using what I assume is dependency injection.

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CompanyController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Now, I don't want to do all database interactions in the controllers, but rather in my other classes.  What I can't figure out, is how to get the ApplicationDbContext from my other classes.  Passing it from the controller obviously won't work because classes could be called from other places than the controller.

If I just try `new ApplicationDbContext();` I get the following error:

```
No database providers are configured. Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services.
```

I feel like this should be something simple, but I am completely lost here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Core is based on dependency injection, since your context has been added in your dependendy container, it's automatically injected by the framework when your controller is instanciated.

### Edit based on comments :

You can setup your classes to support DI, let's suppose you have two class. One that depend on your context, and then second that depend both on your context and your first class :

```
public class MyClass
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public MyClass(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private MyClass _myClass;

    public AnotherClass(ApplicationDbContext context, MyClass myClass)
    {
        _context = context;
        _myClass = myClass;
    }
}
```

Add your classes as a transient dependency in the sevice collections at startup, and let the service provider resolve their dependencies for you :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

    services.AddTransient<MyClass>();        
    services.AddTransient<AnotherClass>();

    //Other configurations removed for brevity
}
```

Change your controller to accept MyClass as injected dependency :

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private MyClass _myClass;

    public CompanyController(ApplicationDbContext context, MyClass myClass)
    {
        _context = context;
        _myClass = myClass;
    }
}
```

You can also have another controller that take AnotherClass as injected dependecy :

```
public class AnotherController : Controller
{
    private AnotherClass _anotherClass;

    public AnotherController(AnotherClass anotherClass)
    {
        _anotherClass = anotherClass;
        // _anotherClass will have both ApplicationDbContext and MyClass injected by the service provider
    }
}
```

You should read the [docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html?highlight=dependency%20injection) of dependency injection of ASP.NET Core, it could help to understand basics of DI. Another [article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2016/02/18/avoiding-the-service-locator-pattern-in-asp-net-core.aspx) from K. Scott Allen that explain some bad practice when you deal with DI.

Comment: That's kind of where I was going.  My only issue there is that means I need to register all my business logic classes in the Startup.cs  Wouldn't it also mean that those classes couldn't call each other?

Comment: Lol... glad to see I'm doing it right. You practically have identical code! Nice. :)

Comment: @Jhorra Sounds like you need to go read up about DI, at least the basics anyway.

Comment: @Jhorra ASP.NET Core has been entirely designed around dependency injection, if you choose that tech stack, you will need to accept some change in your code design.

Comment: Ok no worries let le the time to update my answer to clarify it.

Comment: My specific issue in this instance is I could register all my classes there, and inject them into my controller, but what happens when I need a class to call a method from a different class.  Do I just add any class I might need into the constructor of that class also?

Comment: @Jhorra That last comment kinda suggests you don't fully grasp DI, hence my comment above.

Comment: The answer is yes. Simple as this.

Comment: @DavidG That's why I come here, to bridge the gap between what I read, and what I understand.

Comment: @Fabien Ok, thanks.  I just wanted to make sure I was understanding this correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, this is all very different from my previous development experience.

Comment: @Jhorra I updated my answer, I hope it's better clarify what you missunderstood.

Comment: Also, if it helped, please consider to accept one the two answer, both worth it :)

Comment: @Fabien Sorry, I had upvoted it, but didn't realize I hadn't accepted it.  It's accepted now.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a service class that receives the DbContext in the same way as the controller.

```
public class SomeService
{
    private ApplicationDbContext MyDbContext { get; set; }

    public SomeService(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
       MyDbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public void MethodName()
    {
        // You can now do MyDbContext.SomeDomainModel
    }
}
```

Then register the service in Startup.cs, in your `ConfigureServices` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  // <snipped>
  services.AddTransient<SomeService>();
}
```

And now, in your `CompanyController`, you can add another parameter in the constructor for the `SomeService`, just as you have for the `ApplicationDbContext`.

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private SomeService _someService;

    public CompanyController(ApplicationDbContext context, SomeService someService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _someService = someService;
    }
}
```

All that said, I don't think there's anything wrong with doing your logic in your controller actions to build your ViewModel, accessing the DbContext. The DbContext is what's separating your business logic (in the controller) from the DAL. Some may disagree with me, but you don't need to add additional services to further separate them. Most of the code in your action methods are unique to that action and not going to be reused by other actions. IMO, *those* are the pieces of code to put into services. Things like sending emails and such.